# Share button disappearing from toolbar after the first click and how to add it as command

Tags: codenameone

This is my code guys

```
 ShareButton share = new ShareButton();
         share.setIcon(icon);
         share.setTextToShare("Text yada yada");
         tb.add(BorderLayout.EAST, share);
```

Its just disappearing from the bar after a single click. I also wanna know how to invoke the share functionality on a command thats on the side menu

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently its a simulator problem. Works well on device

Answer (score 0):

The way you add the button to the toolbar is illegal and incorrect. It will behave erratically across devices based on the different behaviors.

You should use a command such as `addMaterialCommand` on the toolbar and then invoke the share functionality in `Display`.